# How do I make OneNote 2007 images searchable when inserted via code?

Tags: c#, ocr, onenote

When I insert an image into OneNote 2007 using C# my images have 'Make Text in Image Searchable' set to Disabled.

How do I insert an image with Make Text in Image Searchable enabled, or how do I enable this property after the image is imported.

I have already imported a lot of images. How to I make the existing imported images searchable?

I already know how to do this manually by right clicking the image and setting the language. The OCR works fine, I just need to do it automatically.